# Query to find "out of sequence" rows

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

My table looks similar to the following:

```
ID_1 | ID_2 | STATUS   | STATUS_TIME | STATUS_BY
------------------------------------------------
1111 | 2222 | 'ONE'    | [timestamp] | 'USER_1'
3333 | 4444 | 'ONE'    | [timestamp] | 'USER_2'
1111 | 2222 | 'THREE'  | [timestamp] | 'USER_3'
3333 | 4444 | 'TWO'    | [timestamp] | 'USER_2'
3333 | 4444 | 'THREE'  | [timestamp] | 'USER_4'
```

Essentially this table tracks status changes to particular items to which ID_1 and ID_2 pertain to. ID_1 may have many rows where it is the ID, but it is connected to the same main object. ID_2 may also have many rows where it applies.

So, to correctly match two rows, you should check if both ID_1 and ID_2 are the same. The problem I am having is due to some poorly designed software we can't tweak or get rid of (for whatever reason).

Status updates don't have any particular order in general, but for example in this case a status of ONE on a particular ID_1 + ID_2 pair should be followed by a status of TWO. Some users skip this step, so I want to see who is skipping it. Here's ideally how I would like this query to work:

- For the current day, I want to see the row which chronologically follows the row with status update 'ONE', ONLY if it's status is not 'TWO'.
- I do not need more than one instance per ID_1 + ID_2, UNLESS the user doing the bad statuses is different.
- This means if USER_1 violated on five entries where ID_1 is the same but ID_2 is different, I only want 1. If USER_1 and USER_2 both violate on ID_1, they need one entry each.
- However, if USER 1 violates on two different ID_1s, both of those need a record.
- A status update of TWO cannot be preceded by anything other than ONE, this case does not need to be considered.

In the case of the above example, I would want the following row:

```
ID_1 | ID_2 | STATUS   | STATUS_TIME | STATUS_BY
------------------------------------------------
1111 | 2222 | 'THREE'  | [timestamp] | 'USER_3'
```

I very much hope I'm being clear enough, please comment if I am missing anything. This is on IBM's DB2 version 9.7 Fix Pack 7. My current 'solution' is long-winded and not functioning properly since it lists all users on the ID_1 + ID_2 who used ONE, even if some of them used TWO and some of them didn't. Any guidance or help is fantastic.

Comment: My attempted answer (the 1st query) returns exactly what you say you want. You may need to provide more complex sample data (in the form of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements) if your actual use case is different, but I think you should be able to figure out by yourself how to move from here. Hint: `LAG(status, 2)` will return the value _before_ the previous (offset by 2); ditto `LEAD(status, 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an analytic function `LAG()` (or `LEAD()`) to find out-of-sequence records.

Depending on the actual data, either of these approaches should work.

This query returns the 'THREE' records that are not preceded by 'TWO':

```
select * from (
 select 
   t.*, 
   lag(status) over (partition by id_1, id_2 order by status_time) as prev_status 
 from test t
) t1 where status = 'THREE' and prev_status != 'TWO'
```

An alternative returns the 'ONE' records not followed by 'TWO':

```
select * from (
 select 
  t.*, 
  lead(status) over (partition by id_1, id_2 order by status_time) as next_status 
 from test t
) t1 where status = 'ONE' and next_status != 'TWO'
```

If you need to look for values in the rows just before the previous (or after the next), specify offset: `LAG(status, 2)` (or `LEAD(status, 2)`).

Comment: This is *almost* perfect for what I am looking for. What I'm looking for is somewhere in the middle. It is essentially the last snippet, but I should be obtaining the status that comes after 'ONE' if it isn't two. Also, I don't think I made it clear in the post but ID_2 is essentially a sub-ID, so this produces duplicates (multiple entries for a single ID_1). I've phrased this a bit better (I think) in the updated bullet points. Also, this seems to run pretty slow (nearly 2 minutes on a database with ~13 million entries).

Comment: Quick update, I sorted the logic out for searching to get the right rows as my final output. Other than that I am a bit stuck.

Comment: Sorry, your "I would want the following" example does not seem to match your description -- I'd expect you to be looking for IDs 1111 and 2222 and user USER_3.

Comment: Apologies, I fixed it to better describe what I'm looking for.

Comment: And you can always use `SELECT DISTINCT ID1, STATUS_BY` from the above to remove duplicates.

Comment: Yep, got that sorted as well :) Only real issue is the time, which I suspect is something to do with the OVER statement. Any way I can speed that up? Generally this is only going to generate a report once at the end of the day, but if a manager wants to be getting "real-time" updates it's going to be a bit annoying.

Comment: Performance is a completely different question. Ask about it separately, providing the actual table definition (with indexes) and the query plan (as shown by `db2exfmt`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct ID_1, Status_By from table t -- only one user by id_1
WHERE status !<>'ONE' -- is not the first row
AND not exists
(select 1 from table t0 where t0.id_1=t.id_1 and t0.id_2=t.id_2 and t0.status_time<t.status_time  and status <> 'ONE') -- is the  row that follows
and status <> 'TWO' -- and the status is not 'TWO'
```

this should work for your conditions 1 and 2, not sure what you mean on your 3 condition because you said it doesn't need to be considered. If the 3rd condition  needs to be tested too, then it can be done adding a "union all"